# Pandas 'builder pattern' vs inplace functions, memory usage

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How does memory consumption compare between these two?

Example 1:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(p).rename(columns={col2: col1,})
```

Example 2:

```
df = pd.read_csv(p)
df.rename(columns={
  col2: col1,
}, inplace=True)
```

Am I correct that this happens in the first example:

1. The DataFrame is read from CSV
2. The DataFrame is copied
3. The copy gets a column renamed
4. The reference to the first dataframe gets dropped,
   and hopefully soon the first DF will get garbage collected

Which means unnecessary copying and possibly double the memory usage, itermittenly?

Comment: `inplace=True` doesn't really guarantee that the memory consumption will be significantly different. The underlying buffer may still be copied, despite the python-level object being mutated in-place. The best way to test this is to profile the memory usage. Note, neither of these pieces of code is an example of the builder pattern.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I meant that the dataframe is copied in `rename`